# renaming sheetname using todays date (only day) when checkbox is checked

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried a lot of stuff but I can't find a fix to it I made it so that a check box if checked, it makes true and false statements in cell `Q46` and function `=IF(Q46=TRUE,DAY(TODAY()),0` in cell `Q47` and in VBA I used this code I know it has a lot of validation that i won't use but I found it online and it works perfectly fine

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Specify the target cell whose entry shall be the sheet tab name.
    If Target.Address <> "$Q$47" Then Exit Sub
        'If the target cell is empty (contents cleared) then don't change the sheet name
    If IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

    'If the length of the target cell's entry is greater than 31 characters, disallow the entry.
    If Len(Target.Value) > 31 Then
        MsgBox "Worksheet tab names cannot be greater than 31 characters in length." & vbCrLf & _
        "You entered " & Target.Value & ", which has " & Len(Target.Value) & " characters.", , "Keep it under 31 characters"
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Sheet tab names cannot contain the characters /, \, [, ], *, ?, or :.
    'Verify that none of these characters are present in the cell's entry.
    Dim IllegalCharacter(1 To 7) As String, i As Integer
    IllegalCharacter(1) = "/"
    IllegalCharacter(2) = "\"
    IllegalCharacter(3) = "["
    IllegalCharacter(4) = "]"
    IllegalCharacter(5) = "*"
    IllegalCharacter(6) = "?"
    IllegalCharacter(7) = ":"
    For i = 1 To 7
        If InStr(Target.Value, (IllegalCharacter(i))) > 0 Then
            MsgBox "You used a character that violates sheet naming rules." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "Please re-enter a sheet name without the ''" & IllegalCharacter(i) & "'' character.", 48, "Not a possible sheet name !!"
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.ClearContents
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

    'Verify that the proposed sheet name does not already exist in the workbook.
    Dim strSheetName As String, wks As Worksheet, bln As Boolean
    strSheetName = Trim(Target.Value)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not wks Is Nothing Then
        bln = True
    Else
        bln = False
        Err.Clear
    End If

    'If the worksheet name does not already exist, name the active sheet as the target cell value.
    'Otherwise, advise the user that duplicate sheet names are not allowed.
    If bln = False Then
        ActiveSheet.Name = strSheetName
    Else
        MsgBox "There is already a sheet named " & strSheetName & "." & vbCrLf & _
        "Please enter a unique name for this sheet."
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

but the problem is the cell I use which is Q47 must be active, its like I must write in it the value for it to rename not check a box so is there a way I can make it so that when I check the box and it becomes "TRUE" in cell `Q46` and write day in `Q47` it automatically change the sheet name to `Q47`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkbox with a linked cell will not trigger the worksheet_change event. Do assign a macro to the checkbox (right click ->view code).

As you said it there is a lot in that code that you don't need but as you want to keep it as did not take it out

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Dim Target As Range
    Set Target = ActiveSheet.Range("q47")
    'Specify the target cell whose entry shall be the sheet tab name.


    If Target.Address <> "$Q$47" Then
    Exit Sub
    End If
        'If the target cell is empty (contents cleared) then don't change the sheet name
    If IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

    'If the length of the target cell's entry is greater than 31 characters, disallow the entry.
    If Len(Target.Value) > 31 Then
        MsgBox "Worksheet tab names cannot be greater than 31 characters in length." & vbCrLf & _
        "You entered " & Target.Value & ", which has " & Len(Target.Value) & " characters.", , "Keep it under 31 characters"
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Sheet tab names cannot contain the characters /, \, [, ], *, ?, or :.
    'Verify that none of these characters are present in the cell's entry.
    Dim IllegalCharacter(1 To 7) As String, i As Integer
    IllegalCharacter(1) = "/"
    IllegalCharacter(2) = "\"
    IllegalCharacter(3) = "["
    IllegalCharacter(4) = "]"
    IllegalCharacter(5) = "*"
    IllegalCharacter(6) = "?"
    IllegalCharacter(7) = ":"
    For i = 1 To 7
        If InStr(Target.Value, (IllegalCharacter(i))) > 0 Then
            MsgBox "You used a character that violates sheet naming rules." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "Please re-enter a sheet name without the ''" & IllegalCharacter(i) & "'' character.", 48, "Not a possible sheet name !!"
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.ClearContents
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

    'Verify that the proposed sheet name does not already exist in the workbook.
    Dim strSheetName As String, wks As Worksheet, bln As Boolean
    strSheetName = Trim(Target.Value)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not wks Is Nothing Then
        bln = True
    Else
        bln = False
        Err.Clear
    End If

    'If the worksheet name does not already exist, name the active sheet as the target cell value.
    'Otherwise, advise the user that duplicate sheet names are not allowed.
    If bln = False Then
        ActiveSheet.Name = strSheetName
    Else
        MsgBox "There is already a sheet named " & strSheetName & "." & vbCrLf & _
        "Please enter a unique name for this sheet."
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```